# Bits and digits are particular cases of what?

Tags: terminology, number-systems

- A bit is a _____(1) that can take two different values: usually 0 or 1.
- A digit is a _____(1) that can take ten different values: 0, 1, ..., 10
- A _____ (2) is a _____(1) that can take 16 different values: 0, 1, ..., 10, A, ..., F.

Questions:
A: Is *guarism* the right word for (1)?
B: What would (2) be? In other words, what is the name for an hexadecimal (1)?
C: What is *the number of different values a (1) can take* called?

Comment: $0, 1, 2, \ldots, 10$ is actually *eleven* different values. Also, the hexadecimal digit $A$ is equal to ten.

Comment: Is "guarism" a typo? That is not a word.

Comment: You seem to be quoting an assignment for some course materials, possibly an online or text based "programmed learning" environment.  The context in which this assignment was given would considerably color the "correctness" of any response, but that context has been omitted when you posted here.  This incompleteness leaves a great burden of guesswork for Readers who might be willing to respond.

Comment: @hardmath: I don't think it is a quote from anywhere, but the OPs original attempt to phrase a question to satisfy their own curiosity.

Comment: The word "bit" is short for "binary digit", by the way.

Comment: "Guarism" is probably an adaptation of the Spanish word "guarismo", which means "digit". According to the Spanish Wiktionary, "guarismo" comes from the Latin "algorismus", making it a cognate of the English words "algorism" and "algorithm".

Comment: @HenningMakholm That is the case, I couldn't think of a better way to pose the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can determine, *guarismo* is a Spanish word that can mean either *numeral* or *digit* (in the sense of a numeric digit).

There is no English word *guarism,* and (as far as I know) there is no English cognate for *guarismo* that would be suitable here.
(*Algorithm* has been suggested, but it does not fit in this context.)

To fill in the blanks that are written "______(1)" in the question,
I think the correct word is **digit.**
There are also less specific words, such as *symbol,* but *digit* seems to be a better choice: it is one of the most specific terms that fits in the blank.

The second sentence should read,

> A *decimal* digit is a digit that can take on ten different values: $0, 1, 2, \ldots, 9.$

We say *decimal digit* in this context precisely because the word *digit* can occur in the context of any place-value system.
Even the word *bit* in the binary number system is derived from the words
*binary digit.*

For base sixteen, we use *hexadecimal digits* or *base-sixteen digits.*

Comment: This is what I was looking for. So, digit is used even for non base-10 systems. The answer to my question C is implicit in your answer: _base_ (turns out also _radix_) is what _the number of different values a digit can take_ is called. Also, I never payed attention to where _bit_ came from; it makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard anything other than "hex(adecimal) digit" for your (2).

I am not sure there is any word for what you ask about for (1) -- or indeed what the precise semantics of the word you're looking for is. The closest word in common use is probably "digit" itself.

I have never heard "guarism", and Google finds no evidence that it's used with a meaning even close to what you describe.

Comment: A common locution for (1) is "place-value", used in connection with positional number systems.